# d3 Plus bar chart how to force fixed max y axis range independent of the max data value

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

I would like to compare 2 d3Plus bar charts, next to ech other, and for that I need that both charts have the same max y value (let's say 1000 even if max data value of the first chart is 700, and max data value of the second is 550).

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "range" property of each chart's y-axis:

```
.y({range: [0, 1000]})
```

For reference, here is the documentation for all of the properties for an axis: https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#x